# i18Next and Input Placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, i18next

There's so much information on i18Next for React but very little for sites needing translations just using the standard i18Next.js.

I have it all working except for one very important thing. I cannot get `<input>` placeholder and custom attributes to translate.

I have seen so many examples saying you should write:
`<input type="text" data-i18n="[placeholder]MYKEY">` and it should output:
`<input type="text" placeholder="My Placeholder">` but it does not.

In my html I can write:

```
<p data-i18n="MYKEY"></p>
```

and it translates perfectly, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my init script:

```
<script src="/i18next/i18next.js"></script>
<script src="/i18next/i18nextHttpBackend.js"></script>
<script src="/i18next/i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.js"></script>

<script>
  i18next
    .use(i18nextHttpBackend)
    .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
    .init(
        {
            fallbackLng: 'en',
            backend: {
                loadPath: 'https://www.example.com/localization/{{lng}}_json',
            }
        }
    )
    .then(() => {
        document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-i18n]').forEach(element => {
            element.innerHTML = i18next.t(element.getAttribute('data-i18n'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using json files to write the translations like this:

```
{
    "contact": {
        "CONTACT_FORM_NAME_LABEL": "NAME",
        "CONTACT_FORM_NAME_PLACEHOLDER": "Enter your name",
    }
}
```

So my actual html for the input field is:

```
<input type="text" data-i18n="[placeholder]contact.CONTACT_FORM_NAME_PLACEHOLDER">
```

I am using the latest i18Next.js version 23.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I needed to load the jquery library for i18next and adjust my init script like this:

```
<script>
  i18next
    .use(i18nextHttpBackend)
    .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
    .init(
        {
            fallbackLng: 'en',
            backend: {
                loadPath: 'https://www.example.com/localization/{{lng}}_json',
            }
        }, (err, t) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $, { useOptionsAttr: true });

            $('body').localize();
        }
    );
</script>
```

Now everything that uses data-i18n="KEY" works perfectly include string attributes.

Remember to load jquery prior to all the i18next javscript.